# How the class references is grouped

Tags: php, yii

How Yii [Class References](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/) grouped its API?
Can you please explain it?
[image: Yii Class References Folder]

Example, i want to do these thing:

1. I want to know maybe Yii already has some class function to generate UNIX time into Georgian Date.
   But which folder maybe contains that's class functions?
2. I want to see all the helpers Yii has? like helper in [CI User Guide](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/)

From example above, what is the good mindset i need to understand Yii Class References Folder?
Since last time i used CI, and its [User Guide](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/) more understandably for me.

Comment: incase you haven't put this question in the yiiframework forum, then do so.

Comment: @DroidUser: i prefer asking at stackoverflow, i believe here i can get answer from the professional :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The classes are grouped by "[virtual namespace](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.namespace)", which is Yii's mechanism for organizing components.

You can see which namespace each class belongs to written in the source file. For example, in [`CDateTimeParser.php`](http://code.google.com/p/yii/source/browse/tags/1.1.8/framework/utils/CDateTimeParser.php) you will find the phpdoc line

```
* @package system.utils
```

As for seeing "all" of Yii's helpers, you can simply follow the tutorial which will get you most of the way there. You can discover the few that are not covered in the tutorial with a little source code exploration.

Comment: WOW, thank you Jon. WHen i see the folder at Yii System as your guide. Now this really clear. Thank you very much :D